# Routing in ASP.NET MVC with multiple areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

> I have two different areas in ASP.NET MVC Web Application.
>    1. Admin
>    2. Site
>
> I want to have the default route of my application to the Site Area
>   i.e    www.mydomain.com/Site/Home
>
> For that I have configured the default route as follows.
>   But this configuration does not work for me.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Areas.Site.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

> The Site Area Route is as follows.

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                name: "Site_default",
                url: "Site/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```

> The Admin Area Route is as follows.

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller="Login",action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```

> Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you've wrong controller namespaces.

Your main route definition should be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" }
);
```

And your areas route like admin area registration should be:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = "Home" },
    new[] { "MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: I don't have any controller in the main folder (MyApp.Controllers). I want to make the Site Area "MyApp.Areas.Site.Controllers" this as default route.

Comment: So you should change the Url in RegisterRoutes to :"Site/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: please first you should try it practically before you answer any question, this way you can waste your and other's time... I have already experimented every this possible scenraios :)

Answer (score 0):

Following steps to do:

1. Create a Project: Project Type: Framework 4.6.1 > WebApi and MVC Web
2. Project Layout will have [Areas Folder]
3. Inside [Areas folder]  you'll find folder [HelpPage Folder]
4. Right-click >> [Areas folder] Select Area > "Give it a name: Administration"
5. Visual Studio Register everything for you.
   Areas

   > Administration
   >
   > > Controllers
   > >     Models
   > >     Views
   > >     AdministrationAreaRegistration.cs
   > >     [Filestructure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZQE4.png)
6. Create a Controller > read write : Give it a name [Admin] and [View] Index[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRxBR.png)
7. Then in your layout add link : Under the normal Home link

   @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)

   @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin", new { area = "Administration" }, null)
8. Click on the link and see your Administration area

Comment: `public class AdministrationAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Administration";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Administration_default",
                "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }`